# How to do listening node js port for the Twitter API

Tags: node.js, express

Below is the code . How can I run below service in Postman (How to do  listening for the below service). I am able to print data in console.log

From config.default I am taking consumer_key,consumer_secret,access_token_key,access_token_secret

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');
var config = require('./config.default');
console.log(config);
var T = new Twitter(config);

// Set up your search parameters
var retweet = function () {
var params = {
  q: '#FIFA2018',
  count: 10,
  result_type: 'recent',
  lang: 'en'
}
T.get('search/tweets', params, function (err, data) {
      // if there no errors
      if (!err) {
        // grab ID of tweet to retweet
        console.log(data);
        var retweetId = data.statuses[0].id_str;
        // Tell TWITTER to retweet
        T.post('statuses/retweet/:id', {
          id: retweetId
        }, function (err, response) {
          if (response) {
            console.log('Retweeted!!!');
          }
          // if there was an error while tweeting
          if (err) {
            console.log('Something went wrong while RETWEETING... Duplication maybe...');
          }
        });
      }
      // if unable to Search a tweet
      else {
        console.log('Something went wrong while SEARCHING...');
      }
    });
}

retweet();
// retweet in every 50 minutes
setInterval(retweet, 30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your node_modules where you have installed the twitter library by npm install. Under twitter, you will see a lib (library) folder. You can check for twitter.js file. This file will list all the functionality. Also, you can see the different URLs used as base.

```js
this.options = extend({
    consumer_key: null,
    consumer_secret: null,
    access_token_key: null,
    access_token_secret: null,
    bearer_token: null,
    rest_base: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1',
    stream_base: 'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1',
    user_stream_base: 'https://userstream.twitter.com/1.1',
    site_stream_base: 'https://sitestream.twitter.com/1.1',
    media_base: 'https://upload.twitter.com/1.1',
    request_options: {
      headers: {
        Accept: '*/*',
        Connection: 'close',
        'User-Agent': 'node-twitter/' + VERSION
      }
    }
  }, options);
```

You can use the URLs according to which functionality you want to use. You do have to provide the request headers and payload according to the API you are using.

Comment: ya I got .But my question is how to make listener for the above service

Comment: What do you mean by listener , can you put a example.